# How to do stuff when i open slider?

Tags: jquery, events, onclick, slider

```
/* Toggle*/
        $(function(){
        $(".collapsible-content").hide();
        $('.news-trigger').toggle(
            function() {
                $(this).toggleClass("opened").parent().next().slideDown();
                $(this).html('Close <img src="img/button-arrow-up.png" alt="" class="collapse-arrow-up">');
                },
            function() {
                $(this).toggleClass("opened").parent().next().slideUp();
                $(this).html('Red more...');
            }
        );
    });
    /* End */
```

How to include \/ that, only wheen i open upper slider

```
/* Count clicks */
$(".count").click(function(){
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    $.get("counter.php?id="+id);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure what you mean?

When you toggle 'news-trigger' you want call your click function?

If this is the case you probably only want to call it once, the first time.

```
    var check = 1;
    $(function(){
        $(".collapsible-content").hide();
        $('.news-trigger').toggle(

            function() {

                $(this).toggleClass("opened").parent().next().slideDown();
                $(this).html('Close <img src="img/button-arrow-up.png" alt="" class="collapse-arrow-up">');
                if(check == 1){
                    $(".count").click(function(){
                         var id = $(this).attr('id');
                         $.get("counter.php?id="+id);
                             }, check = 0);
                         }

                },
            function() {
                $(this).toggleClass("opened").parent().next().slideUp();
                $(this).html('Red more...');

            }

        );
    });
```

Comment: That is the case, but your code works only wheen i press button twice, to roll down and up, i need it to work only wheen i press button one time.

Comment: What is $(".count") part of? Would need to see some page structure. Would `if(check == 1){var id = $(".count").attr('id');
       $.get("counter.php?id="+id);
       check = 0;}` Work?